# Chrome store Publish an add on using gmail id for free as a public option

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script

I developed an add on for chrome store . I plan to give freely to general public. But I can't publish it as a **FREE user without any payment..**

What are the options available to publish as a FREE using gmail account. Plz refer the below image

[image]

Private, Unlisted & Public all are asking to pay a reg. Fee of 5 USD. Is there a way to publish without Fee or without any payment?

Plz clarify if there is any option to publish an addon without any Reg. Fee?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pay the $5 fee no matter what kind of add-on or app you plan to publish, free or not. This is a one-time fee, after paying it and verifying your account you can publish as many add-ons as you want.

I think (not 100% sure on this) that add-ons can be published for free only to your Google Apps domain.

At least it is only $5 once, not $99 every year...

Comment: Hi Azawaza,
           Thanks for your reply, I know its FREE fr G APPS Domain, but I need a confirmation for GMAIL user, if FREE or have to pay this one time fee of 5 USD?

Comment: That's basically what he just claimed above in his answer. IF you're on a Google apps account then free. IF not on a Google apps account, then one time fee of $5.

Comment: Thanks Gerneio, I also know using Google apps account it's free.